# How to use transactions in Yii event

Tags: yii, transactions, yii-events

I know, [how to use transactions in pure DAO](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao#using-transactions) or in [ActiveModel](http://sysmagazine.com/posts/198100/), where transaction is initiated before call to `$model->save()` and rolled back upon any exception.

But how to use transactions, if the only place of code I have access to (no matter, why) is [Yii event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20036464/1469208)?

```
public function beforeDelete()
{
    foreach($this->menuItems as $menuItem) $menuItem->delete();

    return parent::beforeDelete();
}
```

If I initiate transaction there, capture possible exception and rollback entire transaction upon it, then only deletion of relational models (here: menu items) will be rolled back. It will not prevent (roll  back) deletion of master record.

Does preventing deletion of master record, by returning `FALSE` in my own `beforeDelete` in case of exception, is all I need to take care here? Or should I avoid transactions at all in Yii events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about override save method:

```
public function save($runValidation=true,$attributes=null)
{
    $transaction=$this->getDbConnection()->beginTransaction();
    try
    {
        $result = parent::save($runValidation,$attributes);
        if($result)
            $transaction->commit();
        else
            $transaction->rollback();
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        $transaction->rollback();
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I'm accepting your answer as an alternative. My own code, which still uses `beforeDelete` is quite similar to yours. And answer to my own question is (IMHO) "yes" -- preventing deletion of master record, by returning `FALSE` in my own `beforeDelete` in case of exception (after rolling back transaction) seems to be all, that I need to take care in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question with example piece of code to further extend my comment given to *Alex*'s answer:

```
public function beforeDelete()
{
    $transaction = $this->getDbConnection()->beginTransaction();

    try
    {
        foreach($this->menuItems as $menuItem) $menuItem->delete();

        $transaction->commit();
        return parent::beforeDelete();
    }
    catch(Exception $ex)
    {
        $transaction->rollback();
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Both answers seems correct, both are alternative to each other. Though, I accept Alex answer, as better.